# PHP Push notification permission denied IOS

Tags: php

I am currently trying to set up a push notification server using php. I have some code that, if i run it on the command line works. However, when I go to the same php file through a web browser to test that it gives me a permission denied error.

What could possibly be causing this, I belive that it must be something wrong with apache but I have no idea what.

Edit:
I belive it to be an SELinix issue as when I try and run the script these errors appear in the audit log.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1348856835.712:48079): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=587 comm="httpd" dest=2195 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1348856835.712:48079): arch=40000003 syscall=102 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=bfb8c910 a2=4514ad8 a3=10 items=0 ppid=584 pid=587 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=2395 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the server had the SELinux boolean httpd_can_network_connect turned off. Once I turned that on, the script worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely a result of the apache (or nobody) user on your machine not having sufficient rights to do whatever the php script is supposed to do. You are talking about the server-side right? And if so, remove those apple and iOS tags as they are irrelevant.

Comment: After more messing around it seems like it might be an SELinix issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your VHOST configuration? Did you allow an access to your DocRoot directory? Example config below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```